# Name a node in an XML structure from a value obtained from a result in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

So I know if you have this:

```sql
DECLARE @XML XML = 
'<A>
    <First>1</First>
    <Second>2</Second>
    <Third>3</Third>
</A>'

--I can get the name of the node but...
SELECT
    Y.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)') AS NodeName
FROM @XML.nodes('A/*') AS X(Y)
```

As I have seen before in good examples from threads like this:
[How to get node name and values from an xml variable in t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999488/how-to-get-node-name-and-values-from-an-xml-variable-in-t-sql)

But can you go the other way and use values from a result set to name a node?  I feel like I had done this before potentially but cannot remember so thought I would ask.  I am rusty on the permutations of `For XML` and other SQL Server XML creation.

Continued from the above example something like:

```sql
SELECT
    Y.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)') AS "ELEMENT-NODE" --Can I go from table to naming a node?
FROM @XML.nodes('A/*') AS X(Y)
--FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS  -- NOPE
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('A')
```

Is there some syntax that says: "Hey make the value the name of the node"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216006/for-xml-sql-server-variable-element-name-in-output-xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is - in general! - not possible to set the alias of a column from code.

There are two approaches for workarounds:

- `PIVOT`, if you know all existing names in advance
- dynamic SQL

Both have severe limitations when it comes to truly generic needs.

Just as an example your XML above could be solved like this:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = 
'<A>
    <First>1</First>
    <Second>2</Second>
    <Third>3</Third>
</A>
';

DECLARE @colList NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',''' + nd.value('.','nvarchar(max)') + ''' AS ' + QUOTENAME(nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)'))
    FROM @XML.nodes('/A/*') AS A(nd)
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'')
);


EXEC(N'SELECT ' + @colList);
```

But there is no *one-for-everything* answer...

Comment: Ugghhhh, that is what I was afraid of.  I won't shoot the messenger, but I think that is kind of lame on MS's part you can go one way for the shredding of the element nodes but not for creating them from a value.